# On the validity of a simplification made on a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I am given the differential equation

$$y' + \frac2t y = \frac{y^3}{t^2}, t > 0$$

and I am asked to show that the transformation $v = \frac1{y^2}$ makes this a linear equation.

I guessed I had to differentiate $v$ in order to make $y'$ appear and then substitute back into the original equation. So I did:

$$\frac{d}{dt}v = -\frac{2}{y^3}y'$$

And then I manipulated the original equation like so:

$$y' + \frac2t y = \frac{y^3}{t^2} \iff \frac{1}{y^3}\left(y' + \frac2t y \right) = \frac1{t^2}$$

which then makes everything look like something I'd want:

$$\frac{y'}{y^3} + \frac2t \frac{1}{y^2} = \frac1{t^2} \iff -\frac12 v' +\frac2tv = \frac1{t^2}$$

and of course this is an ordinary linear differential equation.

My problem is, can I actually divide through by $y^3$? How can I be sure that $y \neq 0$? I tried to look at the first equation and reason about it with the fact that $t > 0$ but I got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the case $y=0$ separately. Look at the equation: $y=0$ is clearly a solution.

When $y\neq 0$, you define $v=\frac{1}{y^2}$ and what you've done is correct.